# How to agregate integerfield in django template if 2 model share the same field's value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have this model :

```
class LoggedUserDepartement(models.Model):
    department  = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Care')
    date        = models.DateField()
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I have this queryset in my views.py :

```
department_count = LoggedUserDepartement.objects.all()
```

and in my template i have done this :

```
{% for item in department_count %}
   {{item.date }} {{item.login_count}} {{item.department}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
```

This is the result that i get :

```
June 8, 2019 3 css
June 8, 2019 1 carefr
June 9, 2019 2 css
June 9, 2019 1 carefr
```

So what i cannot do here is when i have the same value on the department field how can i merge the 2 items and aggregate the login count value and don't show the value of the date's field ?
Instead of the result that i have now i want to get this one bellow :

```
{% for item in department_count %}
   {{item.login_count}} {{item.department}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
```

```
5 css
3 carefr
```

PS: The date field isn't required in this queryset but i will use it on another querysets in future so i cannot delete it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your model(s)?

Comment: Hi, Willem, i have edited the question with the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make an aggregate like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

LoggedUserDepartment.objects.values('department').annotate(
    total_login=Sum('login_count')
).order_by('department')
```

and then render it like:

```
{% for item in department_count %}
    {{ item.total_login }} {{ item.department }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, I'm not sure that the above modeling is the best way to tackle this problem. There are basically two problems here:

1. a lot of columns have duplicated values, it looks like you should make a model `Department`, and link to it with a `ForeignKey`; and
2. your model also stores aggregated data (well `login_count`s), instead of aggregating over individual records.

This will make it hard to maintain the databas.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and i was about to create a new model department as you suggested because it will be linked also to the user model,  but i didn't fully understand the second part about the aggregated data.